# in linux, how to copy or move files that produce input/output errors (bad sectors), even partially in another hard disk (HDD) without creating image

Tags: linux, file-transfer, bad-sectors, copy

in linux, how to copy or move files that produce input/output errors (bad sectors), even partially in another hard disk (HDD) without creating image.

I have some personal movies and pics which lie on bad sectors.
I want to copy them to another safe place ignoring (or zeroing) bad sector data?
Because they are movies and jpgs, i dont care (so much) for bad sectors cause they can be still playable.

Answer (score 0):

i found answer at [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/489696/recovering-a-file-with-bad-blocks-in-the-middle) . The below command will rescue the damaged file from bad sectors in a new safe place (but missing the bad sector-data).

Note that it says that there are other methods to rescue more data from damaged files from bad sectors.

```
dd if="damagedDISK/damagedfile.avi" of="newDISK/damagedfile.avi" bs=4k conv=noerror,sync
```

Comment: Please give a link to that answer at serverfault.

Comment: Ok i fix it the link. :)

Comment: You should read the advice about `ddrescue` in that link.